# Connect multiple Tex-files: References, Chapter numbering,

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, page-numbering, books, multiple-files

I have several files, all written in the documentclass ''book'' and would like to connect them:

(1) I have worked with the newtheorem-environement. Is it possible to cite some theorem from another file using \label{} and \ref{}? Or also other things, like equations, chapters and pages (with \pageref{}) and so on?

(2) Is it possible to transfer the chapter numbering and also the page numbers to another document? As an example, if my first document has 200 pages and 13 chapters, is it possible that my second document starts with page number 201 and chapter 14? I know that I can change the chapter number and the page number by hand, but my question is if this also works in a dynamical way... e.g.  my second document automatically starts at a higher page number, if I include some more pages into my first document....

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use `xr` package to reference a label from one document to another but if you want page and chapter numbers to continue it's simpler just to process the whole thing as one document.  ignore the separate preambles and make a new master document that `\include` each of the chapters of your smaller documents. Then `\label` etc just works as normal as it is all one document

Comment: You might want to take a look at the `combine` class which assembles a set of individual files (all `book` or all `article`, etc.) into a single document. It does not natively support cross-referencing between the various imports but the `xr` package could help.